# Does 'listunspent 0' return my non-mempool unconfirmed outputs?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, json-rpc, mempool, listunspent

If I have an unconfirmed transaction with a UTXO that belongs to my Bitcoin Core wallet, and that transaction is evicted from my mempool, for example due to high fee-pressure, will `bitcoin-cli listunspent 0` still return the transaction?

I've tried to experiment in regtest mode. I restarted my node with -minrelaytxfee=<higher than my tx>. In this case I didn't get my tx in the response from `listunspent 0`, but I'm not sure this correctly mimics the scenario described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `listunspent`, even if passed `0` as the minimum number of confirmations, will not list coins created in wallet transactions that are not part of the node's mempool at this time.

[Link](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/d1ae96755a0f9d7e12c3f6741c030d8ea6d0416f/src/wallet/spend.cpp#L232-L235) to the relevant code in the Bitcoin Core wallet.